# Execute a large WP_Query with many "AND" Meta_Queries?

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have a custom post type `product`. Visitors can search `products` with many filters. They can set the `color`, the `size`, the `price`, etc. The details of the product are stored with *Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)*.

My solution was a `WP_Query` with `meta_queries`. All `WP_Meta_Queries` are in `AND`-relations.

My problem is: If the visitor creates more filter for the product, the query will always be slower. I think the `INNER JOIN`s on `wp_postmeta` are the problem. I have six `INNER JOIN`s on this table.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: There's a core ticket to reduce that. Currently your only chance is to either build a custom query or rework the query in a `posts_clauses` callback.

Comment: @kaiser do you maybe have link to the ticket. Would like to check it out :-)

Comment: Check out the [#30044](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30044) ticket, it got some interesting patch to dynamically replace the inner joins with sub-queries. I tried it few weeks ago, but there was some problem with it on my install, that I hope to look at in the future ;-)

Comment: The original one was [#24093](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24093), but as @birgire said, there are follow up tickets.

Comment: frankly this is just another premature optimization question that IMO don't belong here but in some MySQL forum. If you need to filter then you need to filter and whether it is fast or slow is irrelevant as you have the requirement to filter. If the filtering by this criteria is rare then it is not important if there is a way to save 10% execution time for it, and if it is common it will be stored in the MySQL cache and returned in almost zero processing time.

Answer (score 6):

You might need a 180° solution here ;)
Think about the problem once more and try this:

> As a visitor I can filter by color and size.

So your solution might be:

```
...
JOIN ... (A)
... (B)
... (C)
WHERE (A.meta_key = 'color' AND A.meta_value = 'red')
OR (B.meta_key = 'color' AND B.meta_value = 'blue')
...
AND (C.meta_key = 'size' AND C.meta_value = 1)
...
```

But actually you can drop some joins using `IN`:

```
JOIN ... (A)
... (B)
WHERE (A.meta_key = 'color' AND A.meta_value IN ('red', 'yellow'))
AND (B.meta_key = 'size' AND B.meta_value IN (1, 2, 3))
```

So start using "IN" for comparing values [like in the manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'meta_key'   => 'age',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'age',
            'value'   => array( 3, 4 ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can even start guessing and have it with only one or no join at all:

```
WHERE meta_key IN ('color', 'size')
  AND meta_value IN ('red', 'blue', 123, 45)
```

This would be fast but might end up in lots of false positives.

Comment: Thank you for your post, but i have installed ACF (advancedcustomfields) and one of the field is a "checkbox". ACF store the data as a serialized array in the meta_value field. For a query you need to use the _like_ compare:

`
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_name', // name of custom field
            'value' => '"red"', // matches exaclty "red", not just red. This prevents a match for "acquired"
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));
`

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/

Answer (score -1):

if you are using woocommerce, you can simply use the [advanced ajax product filters](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/)

This plugin will help you with all post meta.